# Android: Get HTTP error code 429 when Firebase Dynamic Link generation limit exceeds

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am generating Firebase Dynamic Links from Android app. There is a case that I want to handle specifically. Firebase allows 200000 requests per day per project. The Firebase documentation says that you will get error code 429 when this happens but I am unable to see anything in the failure callback to capture this code. My code snippet:

```
Firebase.dynamicLinks.shortLinkAsync(ShortDynamicLink.Suffix.SHORT) {
                link = Uri.parse(buildInvitationLink(config))
                domainUriPrefix = getDomainPrefix(config)
                setAndroidParameters(buildAndroidParameters(config))
                setIosParameters(buildIosParameters(config))
            }.addOnSuccessListener { task ->
                val shortLink = task?.shortLink.toString()
                shareInvitationLink(shortLink)
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                // handle 429 limit exceeds error gracefully here
            }
```

What can I do to detect this limit breach?

Comment: Why don't you direct make the API call instead of using the Firebase client?
[Firebase_Dynamic_Links_Api](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener)

Comment: That way, I guess, you can do your response handing more flexibly!

Comment: `addOnFailureListener` will be passed an exception that you can look at to work out what has failed. I'm unsure what type of exception will correspond to a 429 but that is where I'd start debugging, logging etc.

Comment: Try to check the exception that you get on failure. Like so 
`.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
          Log.w("", "shortLink:onFailure", e);
        }
      });`

Comment: Its almost close to impossible for me to consume 200000 quota and then check the exception type from thrown exception. There must be something inside SDK.